# Trouble connecting to microsoft sql server 2008 from geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sql-server

I am having trouble connecting to ms sql server 2008 from geoserver. my ports seem to be fine.

error message:

> Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message:
>   Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory
>   (The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by
>   using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption.

Comment: Does your SQL Server support SSL encrypted connections?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been discussed on the GeoServer mailing list here:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.geoserver.user/44081

Basically this comes from a (faulty) security update from Microsoft that has been updated, see this link from MS:
https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2992611